# html page is looking odd when inserted in 3D Cart

Tags: html, css

I created the html page and installed on the 3D Cart online store manager.
But the html page looks very odd. Below is the screenshot and code
![Chart Screenshot][1]

In the above pic, there is a chart with 9 dropdowns that is the html page i developed. When i inserted it moved to left most and making the screen looks very odd.
Below is the html code from pastbin.
[html code](http://pastebin.com/STP9dUK3)

Please suggest how can i fix the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the problem that when inserting your "yellow" page into the main page, it shifted the things of the white page to the left ? In that case, probably your problem is in the main page, and the code you posted refers only to the "yellow" page...

Comment: Ya my code is related to only yellow page and when i place it, it shifted to left most and the white page becomes very wide

Comment: After fixing the issue, due to security reasons i removed the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end, i missed closing the table and added as "table" instead of "/table"

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you have some errors in your html.

`<h3>` tags is opened twice, instead of opened and closed;

`<form>` tag is opened outside the `<div id="chart">` , but closed inside it;

For a full list of errors (appearently, 14), paste your whole raw data inside the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org) validating it by direct input.

And as a test, find and remove all your `margin: 0 auto` from your code, they're often the responsibles for this kind of "centering errors"...

Comment: All's well that ends well :)